# Android: how to click on a line in listview after receiving SMS?

Tags: android

```
public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id ) 
    {
        try
        {
            String sender = smsList.get( pos ).split("\n")[0];
            String encryptedData = smsList.get( pos ).split("\n")[1];
            String data = sender + "\n" + StringCryptor.decrypt( new String(SmsReceiver.PASSWORD), encryptedData );
            Toast.makeText( this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I want to decrypt the SMS received on click every time I go in the application, it can only decrypt when there is only one SMS, if it receive 2 SMS, it can't be decrypted because whenever I click, it clicked the whole `ListView`.

Does anyone know how to click separately, line by line?

Answer (score 0):

***Are you doing something like this?:***
***This should work***

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements AdapterView.onItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listr);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // Do whatever else you need to do
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Do whatever
    }
}
```